# Заменить пустые значения pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

подскажите как заменить пустые значения быстро, имею таблицу

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

нужно заменить значения отсутствующие колонки в col1 на значения из col2
apply слишком долог для меня, как вариант np.where НО
можно ли изменить код

```
df.loc[df.col1.isna(), ['col1']] = df.loc[df.col1.isna(), ['col2']]
```

что бы он работал не только c константой, или подскажите, пожалуйста, иные быстрые варианты?

Comment: Насчёт "что бы он работал не только c константой" я вот только не понял. Что вы имели в виду? Так то ваш второй код вполне оптимален, если `NA` в колонке немного. Хотя нужно сравнивать варианты.

Comment: @CrazyElf Конкретно этого кода, он не будет работать значения не обновляться) Можете попробовать
 Благодаря вашему комментарию я понял как исправить его))
df.loc[df.col1.isna(), ['col1']] = df.loc[df.col1.isna(), ['col2']].values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то метод `fillna` может принимать на вход `Series`, так что ему можно прямо нужную колонку передать, из которой он и возьмёт значения, которыми заменит `NA`:

```py
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(df['col2'])
```